# Solve Multivalued function as a Multilevel model?

Tags: panel-data, missing-data, multilevel-analysis, bounds, function

I have a dependent variable (y) that is bounded between 0 and 2. The ideal value of the variable is 1. Values closer to 0 or 2 are theoretically bad (not outliers). I also have a set of potential predictors of the dependent variable.

I have a balanced panel data. I expect that the predictors (x) will have different relationships for dependent variable bounded between 0-1 and 1-2. E.g. ***It is expected that when x increases the y will approach 1 from 0 (i.e. y will increase) as well as approach 1 from 2 (i.e. y will decrease).*** So the bivariate relation will be something like a Multivalued function:

[image: y(x)=1\pm 1/(1+e^{x})]

How do I perform panel data regression to confirm my intuition? Should I bifurcate my data for these two ranges and perform OLS/Fixed/Random effects model? Or solve it as a multilevel model problem? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by that the values are "bad"? Are they outliers?

Comment: @Tim please review I have edited the question.

Comment: You mention that you have a set of predictors X. This makes X a matrix. What do you mean by X increasing? Do you mean all values in X?

Comment: @Sada93 By x increasing I mean moving towards positive values on real number line. e.g. -2 to -1 or +5.